How to train a simple network to predict 2D location without knowing ground truth?
There is a 2D table of known dimension width=4cm, length=6cm. We can place a disc(diameter=0.5cm) at position (x,y).
If the disc stays on the table, there is a function (evaluate_position) that says True, meaning disc is placed. It says False, if disc falls through as that (x,y) is not inside the table. As long as disc stay on the table(if more than half of the disc is inside the table), it is considered as True.

How do we train a simple neural network to predict (x,y) to place the disc. For the predicted value(x,y), update the model weights based on the value from function evaluate_position(), which returns either True or False.

How the weight update would be updated, if the evaluate_position() is outside of the network? Because we only have y_pred, and do not have y_actual. y_pred is evaluated outside of the network.



you are looking for reinforcement learning
